# Фамилия Гиамба. Склонение и ударение

Tags: морфология, склонение-фамилий

Как правильно поставить ударение в фамилии Гиамба? Как она склоняется?

Comment: Правильным для других должно быть такое склонение/ударение, какое считает правильным сам носитель этой фамилии.

Comment: Ана, зачем Вы изменили вопрос? В таком виде он вообще должен быть закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, об ударении надо спрашивать **только** у носителя фамилии. Если же говорить о тенденциях, то фамилия очень, напоминает абхазскую (сравните Ардзинба, Галайба), в них обычно ударение (в русском переложении) падает на **предпоследний** слог. Но это догадки.

Во-вторых, все фамилии, оканчивающиеся на А/Я, мужские и женские, всегда склоняются, за исключением односложных и - традиционно - французских. Иногда говорят еще о некоторых случаях несклонения (финские там фамилии или японские), но такое расширение не является общепризнанным. В любом случае, даже если ударение в приведенной фамилии падает на последний слог, рекомендую склонять по типу "голова", или Али-баба: Гиамба, Гиамбы, Гиамбе, Гиамбой.